# For ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$, show that $I \cap J = $ Ker$(\phi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $I,J$ are ideals of $R$, let $R_{1} = R/I$ and $R_{2} = R/J$.  Show that $\phi \colon R \rightarrow R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$ defined by $\phi(r) = (r+I,r+J)$ is a homomorphism of $R$ into $R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$ such that $\text{Ker}(\phi) = I \cap J$.

I have already proved $\phi$ is a homomorphism and that that Ker$(\phi) = \{ 0 \}$.  How do I show that $I \cap J = \{ 0 \}$?  Here is my proof so far:

$\phi(rs) = (rs+I,rs+J)=(r+I,r+J)(s+I,s+J)=\phi(r)\phi(s)$

$\phi(r+s) = ((r+s)+I,(r+s)+J))=(r+I,r+J)+(s+I,s+J)=\phi(r)+\phi(s)$

$\phi(1) = (1+I,1+J)$ (Is this correct?)

Therefore, $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism.  $\text{Ker}(\phi) = \{ r \in R \colon \phi(r) = (o+I,o+J) \} = \{r \in R \colon \phi(r)=(I,J) \} = I \cap J$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Don't you want to show that $\ker \phi = I \cap J$? How did you get that $\phi$ is injective?

Comment: Yes, so to do that I need to show that $I \cap J = \{ 0 \}$, since Ker$(\phi) = \{ 0 \}$.  I will add more details..

Comment: I am not sure.  I added a couple of questions in my proof.  Maybe I am misunderstanding what the 0 and 1 are in a coset.  I thought that $0+I$ was the 0 and $1+I$ was the 1.

Comment: It is not true that $I\cap J$ is zero, so you are going to have insurmountable difficulty in proving it!

Comment: For an example, just take I equal to J

Comment: @Tim, your conclusion that Ker$(\phi) = \{0\}$ is wrong. Every element of $I$ gets mapped to $0+I$ via the projection $R\to R_1$ and every element of $J$ gets mapped to $0+J$ via the projection $R\to R_2$. Thus the elements of $R$ that are mapped to $(0+I,0+J)$ via $\phi$ are precisely those in $I\cap J$. This doesn't say that $I\cap J$ is $0$ at all.

Comment: @Rise so I edited my proof.  Do I need to say more.  I dont see how it is obvious that $\{ r \in R \colon \phi(r) = (I,J)  \} = I \cap J$

Comment: @Tim, $\phi(r)=(I,J)\Leftrightarrow (r+I,r+J)=(I,J)\Leftrightarrow r\in I$ and $r\in J\Leftrightarrow r\in I\cap J$

Comment: @Rise thank you so much!